# Rhythmbox 3.4.4-ubuntu4 crashes on extract on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: rhythmbox

1. I started up Rhythmbox and was able to extract one CD.  Plays under Rhythmbox (RB) fine.
2. I wanted to load MP3 player, so installed unbuntu-restricted-extras.
3. I tried to extract another CD, then RB crashed.  See stacktrace below.
4. I removed ubuntu-restricted-extras.  RB still crashes on extract.

I'm using an Apple Superdrive by the way, with the "sg_raw /dev/sr0 EA 00 00 00 00 00 01" command.

Any ideas how to get things working?

```
Thread 1 "rhythmbox" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-avx2.S:102
102 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info stack
#0  __strcmp_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-avx2.S:102
#1  0x00007ffff7431fe2 in g_variant_lookup_value ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff74321da in g_variant_lookup ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7e7c805 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librhythmbox-core.so.10
#4  0x00007ffff7e7dccb in _rb_track_transfer_batch_start ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librhythmbox-core.so.10
#5  0x00007ffff7e7e654 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librhythmbox-core.so.10
#6  0x00007ffff7e8cd29 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librhythmbox-core.so.10
#7  0x00007fffe1abfc56 in  ()
    at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/audiocd/libaudiocd.so
#8  0x00007ffff7e82450 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librhythmbox-core.so.10
#9  0x00007ffff74e8bcf in g_closure_invoke ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff751281b in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff7506638 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff7506893 in g_signal_emit ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--  
#13 0x00007ffff692d195 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff766be67 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff7506724 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff7506893 in g_signal_emit ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff766d790 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff7506724 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff7506893 in g_signal_emit ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff766d314 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff792325b in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff7506724 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#23 0x00007ffff7506893 in g_signal_emit ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007ffff7737e6c in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#25 0x00007ffff74ed2df in g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__BOXEDv ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#26 0x00007ffff7506724 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff7506893 in g_signal_emit ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff772f7ab in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff77376ab in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff77382b3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#31 0x00007ffff76feee0 in gtk_event_controller_handle_event ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#32 0x00007ffff78d2015 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#33 0x00007ffff79194a8 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#34 0x00007ffff7506724 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#35 0x00007ffff7506893 in g_signal_emit ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#36 0x00007ffff78e0754 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#37 0x00007ffff77821f0 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#38 0x00007ffff77834ab in gtk_main_do_event ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
#39 0x00007ffff6eb1733 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#40 0x00007ffff6f183d6 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0
#41 0x00007ffff73f48eb in g_main_context_dispatch ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#42 0x00007ffff7447d28 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#43 0x00007ffff73f2023 in g_main_context_iteration ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#44 0x00007ffff692927d in g_application_run ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#45 0x00007ffff7e5ef3d in rb_application_run ()
    at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librhythmbox-core.so.10
#46 0x0000555555555319 in main ()
```

Comment: Somewhat related https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/issues/1487. Otherwise post a new issue https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/issues

Comment: created GNOME > rhythmbox > Issues > #1898

Comment: solved by GNOME team : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/issues/1898

Answer (score 1):

solved by GNOME team: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/issues/1898

```
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly\
```